# Beginner AJAX script not working, stuck on opening XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax

Hopefully, this question isn't too juvenile to ask - but here goes:

I'm trying to learn AJAX, and I'm stuck on a simple content-fetch. Here is my code:

```
request = getHTTPObject();
function useHttpResponse() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = request.responseText;
  }
}
function update_p() {
  request.open("GET",content.html,true);
  request.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
}
```

getHTTPObject is correctly defined, and returns a proper XMLHttpObject. As you probably guessed from the excerpt, the element I am trying to update is id'd "p". It calls the script correctly when a button is clicked, no problem there.

The script seems to stop at line 8, at request.open. There's no error, and the script silently ignores anything afterward.

I don't think I've missed anything, but of course, I probably did. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

content.html is not quoted. Try putting it inside a single/double quote.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - already tried, but the result is the same.

Comment: you did not call send function?

request.send(null)

Answer (score 1):

(This is a comment, not an answer — hence the CW — but I wanted proper markup.)

Fair enough if you're trying to understand the underlying mechanisms, and that's a good thing, but for an actual project, I'd suggest standing on the shoulders of giants instead and using [**Prototype**](http://prototypejs.org), [**Closure**](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com), or one of the [**other libraries**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They simplify a lot of this stuff and — critically — smooth out browser "differences" in many areas.

Comment: Hi T.J., that's exactly what I'm trying to do here. Just learning the underlying concepts, should the need arise. :)